# Managing URLs in a standard way in Codeigniter-HMVC project

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have developed project in codeigniter-HMVC, now I want to manage urls in standard way.

**MY current URLs:**

```
http://xyz/home/contactus
http://xyz/home/aboutus
....
....
```

**I want just like:**

```
http://xyz/contactus
http://xyz/aboutus
....
....
```

I am using HMVC codeigniter structure.

Comment: Is it Codeigniter 2 or 3? Also see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define custom routes in [**`routes.php`**](https://github.com/alzen8work/CodeIgniter-HMVC/blob/master/application/config/routes.php)

```
$route['contact-us'] = "home/home/contactus";
          ^              ^     ^        ^
        New URL      module  Controller  Method
```

In URL call `xyz/contact-us'` which will work fine

[Read more about CodeIgniter route](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Comment: in my mentioned urls, "xyz" will be domain name.. I am using HMVC structure of CI.. I tried.. $route['contact-us'] = "home/home/contactus"; & also tried.. $route['contact-us'] = "home/contactus";

but its not working?

Comment: does `xyz.com/home/contactus` hits your page?

Comment: `$route['contact-us'] = "home/contactus";` this should works then

Comment: it works f9 in MVC structure but same not work in HMVC structure.. any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165619/discussion-between-amita-and-abdulla-nilam).

Answer (score 1):

In ur route.php file u can redirect like this

```
$route['xyz/contactus'] = "xyz/home/contactus";
```

Comment: in my mentioned urls, "xyz" will be domain name.. I am using HMVC structure of CI.. I tried.. $route['contact-us'] = "home/home/contactus"; & also tried.. $route['contact-us'] = "home/contactus";

but its not working?

Answer (score 0):

Edit `routes.php` from `[project-folder]/application/config/routes.php`

To Route a URI as dummy controller and dummy method you can do that with using option route. The main use of routing a URI is to make url pretty and stops to show user main controller & a method name is can possible by route.

**SYNTAX**

`$route['dummy-controller/dummy-method'] = 'main_controller/main_method';`

**EXAMPLE**

`$route['contact-us']='index.php/home/contactus';`

Comment: in my mentioned urls, "xyz" will be domain name.. I am using HMVC structure of CI.. I tried.. $route['contact-us'] = "home/home/contactus"; & also tried.. $route['contact-us'] = "home/contactus";

but its not working?

Comment: May i see your `routes.php` file so, i can help you with that.

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['contact-us'] = "home/home/contactus";

Comment: All the best @Amita